# How to use sort an array with struct entries using mergesort?

Tags: c, mergesort

This is the code that I have written for the `merge` function

```
void merge(struct record *record_arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = mid - low + 1;
    int n2 = high - mid;
    struct record *tmp1 = (struct record *)allocate_memory((n1 + 1) * sizeof(struct record));
    struct record *tmp2 = (struct record *)allocate_memory((n2 + 1) * sizeof(struct record));
    for (i = 0; i <= n1; i++) {
        tmp1[i] = record_arr[low + i];
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= n2; j++) {
        tmp2[j] = record_arr[mid + 1 + j];
    }
    tmp1[i + 1] = (struct record){ 0 };
    tmp2[j + 1] = (struct record){ 0 };
    i = j = 0;
    for (k = low; k <= high; k++) {
        if ((cmp_record(tmp1 + i, tmp2 + j) == 0) || (cmp_record(tmp1 + i, tmp2 + j) == -1)) {
            record_arr[k] = tmp1[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            record_arr[k] = tmp2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

After implementing it, the array is not being sorted and I am getting this error

```
Running TEST2 for 10 inputs
array is not sorted
test2: lib.c:527: check_array_is_sorted_by_uid: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: For starters, as I mentioned under Codeit's answer: `if ((cmp_record(tmp1+i,tmp2+j)==0) || (cmp_record(tmp1+i,tmp2+j)==-1)){` --> `if (cmp_record(tmp1+i,tmp2+j) <= 0) {` ???

Comment: In `merge`, you do `allocate_memory` [nee `malloc`] for `tmp1` and `tmp2` but never call `free` [or whatever] for them. So, you're leaking memory. Even if you do the `free`, this is _slow_ because the time to do the `alloc/free` will exceed the time of the function. You can solve this by having an outer function that does the `alloc/free` once for the _maximum_ sizes. Then, `tmp1/tmp2` are either global scope (easiest) or they are passed as extra parameters.

Comment: You do _not_ need _separate_ loops for `cmp_record` and `cmp_uid` In the first loop, do (e.g.) `int cmp = cmp_record(...); if (cmp == 0) cmp = cmp_uid(...); if (cmp >= 0) {` With that, you only need _one_ temp array and _not_ two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation relies on an error prone technique called *sentinels* where a value known to be larger than all valid values is inserted at the end of the slices.  This is not a good idea, you should instead compare the index values and only compare the structures inside the slices.

Note also that only the left slice needs saving, structures in the right slice are never overwritten before they are compared.

Furthermore, you call the comparison function twice and test for explicit return values `0` and `-1`.  You should just test for `<= 0` to determine which structure to copy.

Memory allocated for the copies must be freed at the end of the `merge` function, otherwise the memory is lost.

Here is a modified version:

```
void mergesort(struct record *record_arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        mergesort(record_arr, low, mid);
        mergesort(record_arr, mid + 1, high);
        merge(record_arr, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(struct record *record_arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = mid - low + 1;
    int n2 = high - mid;

    // save structures from the left slice
    struct record *tmp1 = (struct record *)allocate_memory(n1 * sizeof(struct record));
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        tmp1[i] = record_arr[low + i];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = mid + 1;
    k = low;
    while (i < n1 && j <= high) {
        if (cmp_record(tmp1 + i, record_arr + j) <= 0) {
            record_arr[k++] = tmp1[i++];
        } else {
            record_arr[k++] = record_arr[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        record_arr[k++] = tmp1(i++];
    }
    free_memory(tmp1);
}
```

Comment: AFAICT, OP _sets_ a sentinel but doesn't actually use it in the loops below?

Comment: @CraigEstey In the OP's code, neither `i` nor `j` are gated to *not* ignore them in the primary merge loop. Sooner or later one of them is going land on one, and what should be a condition to *break* the loop and merge the remaining segment instead relies on elements in that segment consistently dominating the comparison against the sentinel of the exhausted segment.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, of course. I was going to mention that in a top comment. But, then I saw chqrlie's code, and I believe he fixed that, so I didn't feel the need to duplicate that.

Comment: "implementation relies on an error prone technique called sentinels " --> you mean, like C _strings_?